# When using an NAudio MMDevice, how do I get the brand name of the device?

Tags: device, naudio

I can get the regular name of a device just fine through NAudio's MMDevice in VB.Net, but this often turns out to be something like "Speakers" or "Microphone".  I need to get both that basic, generic name, as well as the brand name (like "Realtek High Definition Audio").  There doesn't to be any property or function attached to MMDevice that'll handle that, but that doesn't seem like something the whole API would just skip over like that.  This is for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, nevermind, guys.  Sorry.  Apparently I overlooked a function called DeviceFriendlyName.  Sorry, I looked through the list and didn't see it for some reason.  But if anybody searches for this information, just call that function on your MMDevice variable.